# Setup login/register buttons for bbPress?

Tags: bbpress

I installed bbPress and for the most part it was a fairly simple setup. I just had to activate the plugin and the forums showed up automatically on /forums. One thing I wasn't sure about (and I did look through the documentation) was how to set up login/register buttons for unregistered users. Currently, if you go to [this forum](http://davidchoimusic.com/forums/forum/david-choi-talk/) as an unregistered user, it says "You must be logged in to create new topics." Am I supposed to use [shortcodes](http://codex.bbpress.org/shortcodes/) for the login/register buttons? If so, where do I insert them?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert a shortcode on any WordPress page or use the bbPress 'Login Widget' in your sidebar.

http://codex.bbpress.org/widgets/ http://codex.bbpress.org/shortcodes/